# How to make sure all statements are executed?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

how to make sure that the thread in doInBackground() method has been completed or not ?
I want to finish the thread which I have started in doInBackground() method before postExecute gets called.

```
package com.application.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new MyTask().execute(null);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        protected static final String TAG = "Async";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {                     
                        Log.e(TAG, ""+i);                       
                    }
                }

            }).start();
            return null;
        }

      @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e(TAG, "Post execute");
    }

    }
}
```

I want to make sure that thread has to complete in doInBackground method only.

Comment: Please describe your question so that it would be more understandable. If you are using AsyncTask then onPostExecute() methode are there.

Comment: I want to complete the thread in doInBackground method only.onPostExecute does not guarantee you about the threads which are being executed in doInBackground() method.

Comment: Not if he creates a new thread in the doInBackground like in the example.  
Anyways, you should improve your answer ratio a bit.

Comment: I have created new thread in doInBackground() , you can observe

Comment: Yes, and you shouldn't. The AsyncTask handles that automatically.

Comment: I have the need to do this ? Do you know any other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

The [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) automatically creates its own thread, you do not need to do this manually.
When launching an AsyncTask the following happens:

1. `onPreExecute()` is called from the thread that created the AsyncTask.
2. `doInBackground()` is executed on a separate thread.
3. `onPostExecute()` is called and run on the original thread when
   `doInBackground()` is
       completed.

So what you want to do is put your heavy calculation/loading/whatever directly in the `doInBackground()` method, and then finish things of in the `onPostExectute()`.

Comment: Nope.  
It dosn't work in your case, as you create your own thread in the doInBackground.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a new thread from inside doInbackground().

Don't to that and generally, don't mix Thread and AsyncTask. Change your code to

```
   @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {                     
                    Log.e(TAG, ""+i);                       
                }
        return null;
    }
```

This will make sure that all code in doInBackground() has finished before onPostExecute() is called.

Comment: Yes that is also a solution . Thanks.